# /etc/login.defs LOGIN_STRING configuration error

Tags: linux, login, gentoo

In the file `/etc/login.defs` there's the option `LOGIN_STRING` which is commented out (I'm on a gentoo system). When I uncomment this option I'll get the following error message after a successful login:

```
configuration error - unknown item 'LOGIN_STRING' (notify administrator)
```

Everything works fine tho. How can I use this option and why is this error displayed? I've read that it's a deprecated option (?).

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LOGIN_STRING` option is obsolete and doesn't work anymore.  Why it's still in the file is beyond me, probably for historical reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Too bad they removed that option, pretty weird anyway.